# Get iterator value using foreach

Tags: php

I have:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE pirkejo_id=' . $pirkejas . '';
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    if ($row['prek_pav'] != '') {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['prek_pav'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td >' . $row['prek_kaina'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I don't know how to get `$row[i]['prek_pav']`. In my opinion I should change my `foreach` loop to `for`, but don't know how.
Edit:
I want to achieve:

```
<tr>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[1][pavadinimas]" type="text"  placeholder="Prekė" value="<?php $row['prek_pav'] ?>"></td>
<td><input class="input-medium" name="prekes[1][kaina]" type="text"  placeholder="Kaina" value="<?php $row['prek_kaina'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

and update my records in my prekes table in mysql.

Comment: Why do you need to access `$row[$i]['prek_pav']`? You don't seem to have that in your code, so what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: updated. I'll use it in my for to set value from database to input field and then edit it, update to database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using PDO the wrong way. Use parameterized queries instead of substituting dynamic values into the query yourself. If you blindly insert user input into your database queries, then your query will be vulnerable to SQL injection, meaning a user with malicious intent could damage with your data.

Here's the correct way to do it:

```
// prepare the statement -- the place holders allow PDO to handle substituting
// the values, which also prevents SQL injection
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE pirkejo_id=:pirkejas');

// bind the parameters
$stmt->bindValue(':pirkejas', $pirkejas);

// if statement executed successfully, print the results
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if (!empty($row['prek_pav'])) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['prek_pav'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td >' . $row['prek_kaina'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }    
    }
}
```

Note the use of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in the `fetch()` method call above. This tells PDO to return the rows as an associative array with the field names as keys.

Comment: I took advantage for securing my code (:
I print values $row['prek_pav'] to 
<input name="prekes[1][pav]' value='<?php echo $row['prek_pav'] ?>'/>
<input name="prekes[2][pav]' value='<?php echo $row['prek_pav'] ?>'/>

Comment: @pvaitonis: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Did you try this? If you did, did it work? If not, what happened instead? Did it show any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can get using foreach by this way

```
 $i=0;
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    if ($row[$i]['prek_pav'] != '') {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row[$i]['prek_pav'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td >' . $row[$i]['prek_kaina'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
   }
   $i++;
   }
```

Comment: is it possible to get an array of my results?

`foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
if ($row['prek_pav'] != '') {
$prekes = array('prek_pav'=>$row['prek_pav'],                                            'prek_kaina'=>$row['prek_kaina']);
                                }`